# MATLAB - get current workspace

Tags: matlab, workspace

Inside of an function I want to do `assignin(ws, 'var', val)`, but at this point I don't know the workspace ws, which is currently displayed in the workspace window inside the matlab window. I am looking for a statement which replaces my `ws` in the statement above.

Probably a simple and a frequently asked question, but i didn't find an answer.

Comment: From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html): `ws can have a value of 'base' or 'caller' to denote the MATLAB® base workspace or the workspace of the caller function.`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Dan, @user2271770 for anyone asking why one might want to do this: variable variable names can be one reason. `varName = 'myVar'; ...; eval(VarName) = 1` does not assign `myVar` anything. By contrast, `assignin('here', varName, 1)` would be a solution. As to `eval([VarName ' = 1'])`, I never like to include a lot of potentially unknown stuff into eval (injection attacks).

Comment: @bers The reason I asked that was because if you find yourself using variable variable names (or trying to assign values to variables out of scope), I would strongly suggest that the answer is not to use `eval` and `assignin` but to refactor your code so that this is no longer necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seem to want is do an `assignin` in the current workspace. But this is trivial in MATLAB, because is the basic assignment:

```
var = val;
```

The other two accessible workspaces via the `ws` parameter are:

- `'base'`, which is the base workspace (all the scripts will create their variables in it);
- `'caller'`, which is the workspace of the calling function (this workspace is created every time you enter a function, and destroyed when exiting the function), or the global workspace if called from a script.

Comment: @excaza I agree that it may create confusion trough the `global` keyword, which doesn't create the variable in the base workspace. I'm going to correct the answer.

Comment: "But this is trivial in MATLAB, because is the basic assignment:" This sentence is confusing due to grammar. Furthermore, `var=val;` doesn't assign var in the workspace if called from within a function.

Comment: @drmuelr Sorry about the grammar; I could not express that in clearer terms. As for the other note, I beg to differ: `var=val;` *will* assign the variable `var` in the current workspace (the one created by the function call and destroyed as soon as the function exits). True, it will not assign that variable in the base workspace. Here's some perspective on the topic, in case you are confusing a *function workspace* with the *base workspace* : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html

Comment: The asker was trying to assign to a variable "which is currently displayed in the workspace window inside the matlab window", which is the base workspace, so this is still confusing. Is it correct to say "When `var = val;` is called inside a function, it is the same as doing `assignin('caller', 'var', val);`"?

Comment: @drmuelr The confusion is even more fuelled by the fact that the workspace window shows different things depending on the way the code is executed (running or stepping though statements). The `'caller'` syntax will not assign in the current workspace, but in the workspace of the function that called the currently running function. So is not the same as `var = val;`.

Answer (score -1):

I used the following workaround:

```
function main()
...
assignhere(name,value)
...
return

function assignhere(varname,varvalue)
assignin('caller',varname,varvalue);
return
```

although I would prefer to have access to the current workspace directly

Comment: You do have access to the current workspace directly. This is a weird workaround. `eval([name,'=',value])` does the same thing. But if you find yourself needing this, you **really** need to refactor your code. You should not have "dynamic" variable names, or refer to local variables using strings. Use cell arrays or struct arrays instead. For example, you can do `data.(name)=value`.